# Problem with print composer when exporting a map with Google Maps Plugin in the background

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, print-composer

Whenever I try to export a map with the Google Maps plugin in the background, it exports but just exports to a blank document. When I turn the Plugin off so it is not in the background, it prints fine. Why is this?

Comment: Correction. When I attempt to export it as a PDF the whole map disappears in print composer and the PDF is not able to be opened. I have no idea what is causing this.....please help

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using? I just tested this in 2.2 and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 3):

I gave up using the OpenLayers plugin a long time ago and tried to use other services like WMS whenever possible because of the multitude of quirks with offsets, printing etc.

For some time, there is the [QuickMapServices](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/quick_map_services/) plugin around, which so far works great. You can work there with any projection you like, and printing works, too (Never tried with PDF, cause I do not need them)

After installing it, go to **Web->QuickmapServices->Settings->Contributed services** and click "Get contributed pack" to get more than the default list of services.